# How to set windows environment paths, especially for caffe, afer downloading pre-built binaries?

Tags: python, environment-variables, caffe

I have downloaded the prebuilt binaries for caffe in windows from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows. After downloading them I do not really know how to get python to know caffe. When I write `import caffe` on the python script it states that it it can not find it - of course.

After downloading I have the following folders:

```
bin, include, lib, python and share
```

How do I proceed to make it global available to all my python scripts ?

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.6 and Anaconda.

Comment: looks like python can't find caffe,check if you ve added it on pythonpath and make sure you add  the full path  like C:\Projects\caffe\python, not only just caffe folder since you want python to find it ,here is an example of adding a module to pythonpath https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: thank you really much for your reply - however, does this also work the same way when I have not installed Python but installed it via Anaconda / Spyder ?